# Don't play Favorites

Tags: discussion

Why is the "Favorite Question" feature (that little star under the vote-arrow) used so rarely here? Can someone explain what its function is and when one should or shouldn't use it?

Comment: See if you still have any questions after reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585.

Comment: Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: Because I wanted first to know if you still had question after reading it (in which case you would refine this question and *then* I'd answer it if I could).

Comment: @msh210 That seems sufficient. Do we know if/when the notifications will resume?

Comment: I don't: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52094, on which Jeff commented as recently as this January "we haven't quite figured out a way".

Answer (score 3):

There's [a meta.stackoverflow FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585) that answers the "what its function is and when one should or shouldn't use it" part of your question. That post should be kept up to date as the feature changes, so (to avoid needing to update this also) I won't copy here what it says. It doesn't, however, address the "used so rarely here" part of your question, which I don't know. Some anecdotal information: there are a few questions on meta.stackoverflow that I like to see updates to. I have them favorited so that I can, whenever I want, quickly check [my favorite-question list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/161792/msh210?tab=favorites) to see if anything is new.

Comment: You can favorite your own question!? Why?

Comment: From the MSO FAQ post, "Notifications will include comments to the question, edits, new answers, and edits to answers.", which is more notification than ownership supplies, so it makes sense you can favorite your own question. (Owners don't get notified (by the usual means) on edits to their questions or on edits to answers thereto.)

Comment: Owners now get notified of edits to their posts (modulo occasional flakiness in the notification system), but there's no notification of edits to answers, even the one you accepted, so favorites are a way to track that.  (If you ask a lot of questions, though, it's probably not a workable way to track *all* of them.)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason that this feature is so little used is because most people don't know what it is and what it does. I came across this meta post in my search to find out more about it. AFAICT this feature is not mentioned in the local help section - if it was maybe people would start using it. (Now that I know what it is I plan to start using it myself).

Another suggestion would to be publicize this feature in the community bulletin for a while.